# parse date by prompting user for date format?

Tags: java, parsing, date, time, jodatime

My application reads a csv file provided by the user. This csv file contains a field for date and / or time, formatted in any way the user chose it. Like:
1999/10/28
or
2000-01-01,3PM-02-59

I want to offer the user the possibility to indicate the formatting of the date and time in this field. So, I'd have an input window saying:
"Specify the formatting of your date/time field"
"Example: for 1999/10/28 format, input yyyy/mm/dd"
"Other example: for 2000-01-01,3PM-02-59,input yyyy-dd-mm,hh-mm-ss"

I would retrieve their input as a string, then do some complicated and annoying operation to derive a regular expression from this string, which I would then apply in the csv parser to identify years, months, days, hours, etc. in the "date and time" field.

**My question before embarking in this:** is there a library which already does this kind of thing? Am I reinventing the wheel? Is there a much more obvious approach I'm missing?

Thanks a lot!

PS: yes, it is all about users providing their own strange date and time formats. No need to suggest that it would be easier with a a uniform format! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Joda Time you can use multiple parser, you can check this SO answer 
[Using Joda Date & Time API to parse multiple formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/using-joda-date-time-api-to-parse-multiple-formats)

Comment: Thanks! That's a first step. I would need to dynamically create a new parser based on the input of the user? Seems feasible...

Comment: Yes, since the user is prompted to choose the format he prefers, you can pass that as input parameter to the method in charge of the date parsing

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: thanks but this is the opposite of what I want. SimpleDateFormat takes a formatted date and converts it in a variety of forms. I need to take a date formatted in all strange forms, and turn it into a single format.

Comment: the strange forms you talk about, at least the user know what they are right ? so you can ask him for that format, create a SimpleDateformat with it and parse the date, then you use another SimpleDateFormat object to format the date to the desired format.