# Java parse different date types

Tags: java, parsing, date

Is there some simple way to parse different type of dates in java without playing with the date strings?

I have to deal with 6 different types of date:

- 16 May 2013 19:27:12 CEST
- Tue, 14 May 2013 13:15:00 +0200
- 2013-05-20T12:01:57Z
- 13/11/2012 15:30:00
- 11.11.2013
- 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

I don't know if a date will arrive in one format or the other from the server...

thank you!

Comment: check out JodaTime http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I want to keep the package size as small as possible so I don't think I'm going to use an external library only for dates. Thank you anyway! This is a good answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the stock "Use Joda-Time" answer, in Joda-Time you can create a `DateTimeParser` for each of your 6 formats, then append them to a single `DateTimeFormatter`.

See the accepted answer to this question:
[Using Joda Date & Time API to parse multiple formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/using-joda-date-time-api-to-parse-multiple-formats)

Comment: I think this is the best answer because I didn't specify the package size issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over all formats and try to parse, ignore the exception. If no format fits, throw an exception.

[similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024604/1651233)

Answer (score 1):

The best-known alternative to the standard API is Joda-Time.
Also JSR 310 an improved Date/Time API for Java SE 7

Comment: This is a good answer but I should keep the package size as small as possible so I don't think I'm going to use external libraries only for dates. Thank you anyway of course1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an actual "easy" way to deal with such different date formats.
If you have the option to nail a "standard date format" to the server that would be the easy way.

A common approach is to build a DateParser for every 'freaky' date format that you have to deal with. Here's an example for your first date, using Joda Time:

```
String date1 = "16 May 2013 19:27:12 CEST";
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendDayOfMonth(2)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendMonthOfYearShortText()
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendYear(4, 4)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendHourOfDay(2)
            .appendLiteral(":")
            .appendMinuteOfDay(2)
            .appendLiteral(":")
            .appendSecondOfDay(2)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendLiteral("CEST")
            .toFormatter();

        DateTime parseDateTime = fmt.parseDateTime(date1);

        System.out.println(parseDateTime);
```

I hope this will help you build DateParsers for the other cases. And remember - always save your dates in relation to UTC!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code, for date string like 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700 we need to use following format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700");
System.out.println(date);
```

details are available in below mentioned link

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)