# joda date DateTimeFormatterBuilder append does not work

Tags: java, jodatime, date-format

Code first.

```
@Test
public void testDateFormat()
{
    // this is ok
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime("2014-5-15 20:00:00");
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parseDateTime("2014-5-15");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
            // ues these way is also failed.
            //.append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("xxxx"))
            //.append(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("xxxx").getParser())
            .toFormatter();

    try
    {
        formatter.parseLocalDateTime("2014-5-15 20:00:00");
    }catch (Exception ignored){System.out.println("Failed A");}
    try
    {
        formatter.parseLocalDateTime("2014-05-15 20:00:00");
    }catch (Exception ignored){System.out.println("Failed B");}
    try
    {
        formatter.parseLocalDateTime("2014-5-15");
    }catch (Exception ignored){System.out.println("Failed C");}
    try
    {
        formatter.parseLocalDateTime("2014-05-15");
    }catch (Exception ignored){System.out.println("Failed D");}
}
```

Output

```
Failed A:Invalid format: "2014-5-15 20:00:00" is too short
Failed B:Invalid format: "2014-05-15 20:00:00" is too short
Failed C:Invalid format: "2014-5-15" is too short
Failed D:Invalid format: "2014-05-15" is too short
```

Everything failed. Am I doing something wrong? It looks like it should be OK.

Comment: How does `2014-5-15 20:00:00` fit into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssyyyy-MM-dd` or any of the other examples you provide for that matter?

Comment: append is concat all ? not a array of formatter ?

Comment: No, append is concat.  It's not, "I have a bunch of formatters, try them all until one passes"...you're going to need to write that yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks, trying to write this on my own. :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/)

Right way to do this.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(null,
                    new DateTimeParser[]{DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").getParser(),
                            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").getParser()})
            .toFormatter();
```