# converting string representation of unknown date-format to Date in java

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a string that represents a date. **I do not know the date format of the string.** But for example only, it may be any of

- 2015-10-14T16:41:42.000Z
- 2015-10-14T19:01:53.100+01:00
- 2015-10-14 05:20:29

or any valid format that a website may use to describe date in a meta tag (so the format will be official, as opposed to whimsical, but the set of possibilities is not small).

Can I use joda-time to solve this issue? How about `java.util.Date` or anything else?

**update**

I think I find a Javascript equivalent of what I am looking for

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

But I need an answer for **Java**.

Comment: [Using Joda Date & Time API to parse multiple formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/using-joda-date-time-api-to-parse-multiple-formats)

Comment: Both of these suggestions require me to know the format beforehand. The very title of my question specifies "unknown" format :). Do you guys know by any chances of a way to get all possible date formats for my circumstance? (Hoping it's a very small set, of course). I don't mind writing multiple parsers, but the thing is the format can be anything that is valid for an html meta tag that contains date.

Comment: I see a lot of up votes for the Jado Date link, but it is missing the ball on my question. So I have added a link to a js equivalent.

Comment: There's no "simple" answer and the general answer is to use a List of formats and keep trying to convert the value against the List of formats until one works

Comment: +1 to MadProgrammer — that's what I did. I have a `DateParser` class that contains several pre-defined date formats I expect, plus you can provide your own list of formats per-call.  Simple call is `DateParser.parse(dateString)` through complex `public static Date parse(String dateString, boolean strict, DateFormat... mine)` choosing strict or lenient parsing with varargs of your own date formats to try first, then try the fallback built-ins.

Comment: "but the **set of possibilities** is not small" - self-answering questions are the best.

Comment: @Gimby your comment is neither intelligent nor helpful nor necessary: the OP provides a link where such a function actually exists for JavaScript. So this is a valuable question. And perhaps Google or Oracle or joda-time or whoever is responsible for creating authoritative Java functions should pay attention. A function like this in Java would be invaluable to many developers.

Comment: Even though there may be a huge number of actual formats, if there are a few conforming rules for those formats, one could write a parser that picks the relevant pieces out. A common/conforming theme in the OP examples is that, on the whole, the pieces are arranged in the order `year month day hour minute second` with optional time-zone information and/or offset. Knowing that, you could find those pieces then attempt to make sense of the yet-unparsed bit, such as the `space-or-T` separator between date and time. Parse instead of match.

Comment: @KonsolLabapen feel better now? If you have trouble with a comment flag it

Comment: @StephenP what would be the format for the ones I have so far? For jodatime

Comment: @KatedralPillon yours (assuming always a 24-hour clock) look like `4-digit-year, literal_dash, 2-digit-month, literal_dash, 2-digit-day, one-space-or-literal_T, 2-digit-hour, literal_colon, 2-digit-minute, literal_colon, 2-digit-second` (etc).
A regex (w/o checking valid ranges) is _like_ `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3})?(.*)?` (add proper capturing groups to extract pieces) the `(\.\d{3})?` is optional 3-digit hundredths of a second; the final `(.*)?` is the optional time-zone info, which needs more parsing to tell if its a zone (Z, EST, etc.) or an offset (+01:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is not a real "java" solution, but if you have found a Javascript one, than you can use the Javascript solution in java using the [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/).

just a little quick and dirty... :)

here is a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, ParseException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    String[] dateStrings = new String[] {
            "2015-10-14T16:41:42.000Z",
            "2015-10-14T19:01:53.100+01:00",
            "2015-10-14 05:20:29" };

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    for (String d : dateStrings) {
        String script = "new Date('" + d + "')";
        Object eval = engine.eval(script);
        Date parsed = sdf.parse(eval.toString().replace("[Date ", "").replace("]", ""));
        System.out.println(eval + " -> " + parsed);

    }

}
```

that prints out:

```
[Date 2015-10-14T16:41:42.000Z] -> Wed Oct 14 18:41:42 CEST 2015
[Date 2015-10-14T18:01:53.100Z] -> Wed Oct 14 20:01:53 CEST 2015
[Date 2015-10-14T03:20:29.000Z] -> Wed Oct 14 05:20:29 CEST 2015
```

The eval.toString() part can be improved obviously. as the locale settings...

Comment: I am looking at the page, but I am not really sure what I am looking at. Do you mind showing a short code of how I would call the JS `new Date(dateString)` construction in Java using the ScriptEngine?

Comment: I don't know if your example works, but the ScriptEngine idea should, so I am testing some code (yours and my own versions) and will report back once I am successful. In the meantime +1.

Comment: shouldn't the following work? `String script = "var date = new Date('" + dateString + "'); var timestamp = date.getTime();";` and then 
       `long timestamp = ((Long) engine.get("timestamp")).longValue(); `?

Comment: yes it works but you have to eval the script string `engine.eval(script);` and then get the var but casting to Double and not to Long: `long timestamp = ((Double) engine.get("timestamp")).longValue();`

Comment: The answer may not be native Java, but until Joda-time gives use a better answer, this is it. I use the code snippet I show you, with the `Double` correction.