# Joda-Time create LocalDate from String with Pattern

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime, formatter

I'm trying to create a LocalDate object, using the JodaTime library, from an input string. The string comes from a database that I have no control over. The input date of birth looks **exactly** like this:

```
1963-07-19T00:00:00.000+0000
```

I just want the `1963-07-19` portion, I don't want the time portion. So I tried to implement a formatter like so:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And then create the LocalDate object like so:

```
LocalDate dob = formatter.parseLocalDate(dateOfBirth);
```

But I get the error:

```
Invalid format: "1963-07-19T00:00:00.000+0000" is malformed at "T00:00:00.000+0000"
```

I've also tried a formatter like so:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

But then I get the error:

```
Cannot parse "1963-07-19T00:00:00.000+0000": Value 0 for clockhourOfHalfday must be in the range [1,12]
```

And idea how to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example won't work because [`parseLocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalDate-java.lang.String-) has to match the entire input string against your pattern.

For your second example, according to the [javadoc of `DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), the pattern letter `h` defines

> ```
> h       clockhour of halfday (1~12)  number        12
> ```

It looks like you want

> ```
> H       hour of day (0~23)           number        0
> ```

Comment: Perfect, this worked. I'm just worried the DB will spit back something weirder later on and crash the prog. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @richard If you need to, jodatime allows you to define multiple parsers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/using-joda-date-time-api-to-parse-multiple-formats).

Answer (score 1):

The date you have shown is in a standard format - the ISO8601 standard.

Joda-Time has a special class for creating `DateTimeFormatter` objects for this particular standard - the `ISODateTimeFormat` class.

So you can do this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
LocalDate dob = formatter.parseLocalDate(theDate);
```

See the [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) for other methods dealing with different variations of the ISO-8601 date format. For the particular string you have shown, the `dateTime()` method should work.