# Generic way to convert a given String date in any format to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, date

I want to convert a string representation of date in any format to `java.sql.Timestamp`,(format is also provided)

we have tried using `Timestamp.valueOf()` and `Date.valueOf()` but both these method requires String in a particular format,What i need is a generic method which will convert a given String date in any format to `java.sql.Timestamp`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you tried with SimpleDateFormate ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/using-joda-date-time-api-to-parse-multiple-formats

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` itself has no format at all and is supposed to be used on the back-end side (JDBC). `java.sql.Timestamp` represents the number of milliseconds, since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`. Formatting a date (using `SimpleDateFormat`, for example) in a specific format is only involved, when a date is to be displayed somewhere which `java.sql.Timestamp` is not meant for.

Comment: @ctdex Please search StackOverflow before posting. The question of parsing any arbitrary date-time format has been addressed many many times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the string and know the format you can try something like:

```
dateStr = "25 December 2015"
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateStr);
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTimestamp());
```

Or similar:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
java.util.Date date = simpleDate.parse("2015-12-31 09:45:52.189");
java.sql.Timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks,yes that's works but what if we don't know the format beforehand it is possible with SimpleDateFormat,by the way i am using java7

Comment: I don't know a specific method for that. You could try to define several date formats, and surround the method with a `try {} catch (ParseException e)`