# DateTimeFormatterBuilder fail to chose format

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I've configured formatter:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        .append(forPattern("MM/dd/yy"))
        .append(forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy"))
        .toFormatter();
```

and trying to parse a string `2017-08-29`

```
LocalDate.parse(dt, DATE_FORMATTER).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toLocalDateTime()
```

I'm getting error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2017-08-29" is too short

Error gone if I leave "yyyy-MM-dd" the only format in the builder.

Am I misusing the API? I would like the parser to try another format if it fails with first one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307330/using-joda-date-time-api-to-parse-multiple-formats

Comment: I don’t know Joda-Time. Could it be that your formatter expects those three formats after each other in the string?? Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `append` method, you're creating a formatter that accepts all the three patterns, one after the another (all the three are required).

If you want to accept any of the three formats (just one of them), you must use `appendOptional` instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").getParser())
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy").getParser())
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy").getParser())
    .toFormatter();
```

Now you can parse any of the three formats:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2017-08-29", DATE_FORMATTER).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("08/29/17", DATE_FORMATTER).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("Aug 29, 2017", DATE_FORMATTER).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toLocalDateTime());
```

All of the above outputs:

> 2017-08-29T00:00:00.000

---

**Just one note**: the third formatter uses the month short name (`MMM`), and the code above assumes that the system's default locale is English (when you create a formatter, by default it uses the language that corresponds to the system's default locale).

But this can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to specify a `java.util.Locale` in your formatter.

Example: if month name is always in English, just use the equivalent locale:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").getParser())
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy").getParser())
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy").getParser())
    // use English locale
    .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Just change the locale to the one that best fits your needs. [Check the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for more details.

---

As reminded in the comments, you can also create an array of parsers and use in the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
// array with all possible patterns
DateTimeParser[] parsers = new DateTimeParser[] {
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").getParser(),
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yy").getParser(),
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, yyyy").getParser() };

DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // use array of all possible parsers
    .append(null, parsers)
    // use English locale
    .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This works the same way as the previous one.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

*If you can't (or don't want to) migrate from Joda-Time to the new API, you can ignore this section.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The API is very similar when it comes to create the formatter and parsing it:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy"))
    // use English locale
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2017-08-29", DATE_FORMATTER).atStartOfDay());
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("08/29/17", DATE_FORMATTER).atStartOfDay());
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("Aug 29, 2017", DATE_FORMATTER).atStartOfDay());
```

All the above create a `LocalDateTime` with the value that corresponds to `2017-08-29T00:00`.

You can also use optional patterns (delimited by `[]`):

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][MM/dd/yy][MMM dd, yyyy]", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This works the same way as the above.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get some headache when I see people all the time suggesting a serial chain of optional sections although the intention is to realize an or-syntax (which is not supported by standard Java). IMHO, using optional sections that way is still a dirty hack for the missing or-feature. And Joda-Time has such a thing, see the better [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4330486/2491410) about this subject. For comparison, see also the open [JDK-issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132536)

Comment: Another example for a better or-realization, see my lib [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.Builder.html#or--)

Comment: @MenoHochschild Indeed, I forgot that Joda-Time has the option to have an array of parsers (and I had this code, just didn't remember when writing this answer). I've udpated the answer, thanks a lot!